# splitting matrix of strings into numeric matrix in R

Tags: r, string, matrix

I have a (large) matrix of strings of two numbers. I want to convert the matrix to a numeric matrix where the strings are separated into different columns while preserving the row order and string order of the original matrix. I am doing this in R, in which I am mostly a novice/self-taught. Example input and desired output below

```
input
test <- matrix[1:5,1:5]
test
     col1    col2   col3   col4   col5
row1 "0,0"   "0,0"  "0,0"  "0,0"  "0,1"            
row2 "0,0"   "0,0"  "0,0"  "0,0"  "0,0"            
row3 "0,0"   "0,0"  "0,2"  "0,0"  "0,0"            
row4 "0,0"   "0,0"  "0,2"  "0,0"  "0,0"            
row5 "0,0"   "0,0"  "0,0"  "0,0"  "1,0"    

desired output
      col1 col1.1 col2  col2.1 col3  col3.1 col4  col4.1 col5  col5.1
row1  0    0      0     0      0     0      0     0      0     1            
row2  0    0      0     0      0     0      0     0      0     0            
row3  0    0      0     0      0     2      0     0      0     0            
row4  0    0      0     0      0     2      0     0      0     0            
row5  0    0      0     0      0     0      0     0      1     0
```

So far I've tried using strsplit and lapply/unlist, and I can make a matrix that doesn't preserve structure of the original matrix, but I need the original structure for downstream applications.

```
bad output
> matrix(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(test,","))),nrow=nrow(test))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    0    2    0    0    0     0
[2,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1     0
[3,]    0    0    0    0    0    2    0    0    0     0
[4,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     1
[5,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option in `base R` with `read.csv` on each of the column

```
do.call(cbind, lapply(test, function(x) read.csv(text = x, header = FALSE)))
```

-output

```
col1.V1 col1.V2 col2.V1 col2.V2 col3.V1 col3.V2 col4.V1 col4.V2 col5.V1 col5.V2
1       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       1
2       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
3       0       0       0       0       0       2       0       0       0       0
4       0       0       0       0       0       2       0       0       0       0
5       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       1       0
```

---

If it is a `matrix`, can use `apply` with `MARGIN = 2` to loop over the columns and read the data with `read.csv`

```
do.call(cbind, apply(as.matrix(test), 2, function(x) 
       read.csv(text = x, header = FALSE)))
```

#### data

```
test <- structure(list(col1 = c("0,0", "0,0", "0,0", "0,0", "0,0"), 
      col2 = c("0,0", 
"0,0", "0,0", "0,0", "0,0"), col3 = c("0,0", "0,0", "0,2", "0,2", 
"0,0"), col4 = c("0,0", "0,0", "0,0", "0,0", "0,0"), col5 = c("0,1", 
"0,0", "0,0", "0,0", "1,0")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("row1", 
"row2", "row3", "row4", "row5"))
```

NOTE: Here, we used the initial input data as `data.frame`

Answer (score 1):

Another base R option with `read.csv`

```
> read.csv(text = do.call(paste,c(asplit(test,2),sep = ",")), header = FALSE)
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   1
2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
3  0  0  0  0  0  2  0  0  0   0
4  0  0  0  0  0  2  0  0  0   0
5  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1   0
```

## Data

```
> dput(test)
structure(c("0,0", "0,0", "0,0", "0,0", "0,0", "0,0", "0,0", 
"0,0", "0,0", "0,0", "0,0", "0,0", "0,2", "0,2", "0,0", "0,0",
"0,0", "0,0", "0,0", "0,0", "0,1", "0,0", "0,0", "0,0", "1,0"
), .Dim = c(5L, 5L), .Dimnames = list(c("row1", "row2", "row3",
"row4", "row5"), c("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5")))
```